# CUT and PASTE in Ace editor

Tags: jquery, ace-editor

I am using ace editor and i am not able to CUT and PASTE programatically. For `Undo` and `Redo`, I used the following code. How to perform CUT and PASTE?

```
editor.getSession().getUndoManager().undo(false); 
editor.getSession().getUndoManager().redo(false);
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem too.

Answer (score 4):

For undo it is better to use `editor.execCommand("undo")` (and similarly for the redo).

Cut and paste are trickier because the commands in ace do not modify clipboard. If you need to support only the new browsers you can use navigator.clipboard the following way:

```
// paste
navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function(text) {
    editor.execCommand("paste", text)
})

// copy / cut
var text = editor.getCopyText()
editor.execCommand("copy") // or cut
navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
```

old browsers are trickier to handle https://github.com/c9/core/blob/c4d1c59dc8d6619bdca3dbe740291cd5cd26352c/plugins/c9.ide.clipboard/html5.js

Answer (score 1):

For the copy/cut operation try using **getCopyText** function, which copies the text that has been selected.

```
var copiedText = editor.getCopyText()
```

In order to paste the content, you selected you can use the **insert** function.

```
editor.insert(copiedText)
```

As you are looking for a CUT function in particular, once you copy the text you can make a .insert("") which replaces the whole selection just as how the CUT functionality works.

Comment: for pasting, it doesn't gives the copied value from the keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl + C, Ctrl + X). Any solution on that?

Comment: Try overriding if Ctrl-V if you would like to. But did you put your copied text in any global field and tried using that variable while pasting?

Comment: Yeah i did store it in global field.